# Validate PHP form field if not left empty

Tags: php, validation

I have a bit of a problem with my PHP form validation that I could use some help with.

I got an optional field which should be validated only if the user fills it, otherwise the form should be processed as normal. Here's the validation for the field:

```
if (!preg_match("/(0?\d|1[0-2]):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i", '$start')) :
        $errors->add('submit_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The time is incorrect', 'appthemes'));
        endif;
```

Might be simple, but at the moment I just can't get my head around how can I bypass the validation if the field is left empty. Any ideas?

Comment: `'$start'` is incorrect. That creates a string whose literal value is the text `$string`, not the contents of the variable $string. the quotes are entirely superfluous and can be removed. If you MUST use quotes, then use `"$string"` instead (which is still useless, but less incorrect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!empty($your_field) && !preg_match(...))
```

PHP tests if the field is null before testing the regex. 
If the field is null PHP will jump to the next instruction.

Comment: This is correct; using the empty check avoids the expensive error/notice that is generated if $start is not set.

Comment: Thank you all, but this was the one I got working right away and went with it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the rest of your code inside of this, it will only trigger if $start isn't empty,

```
if (trim($start)) {
    // put other code in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['field_name'])) {
if(!preg_match("/(0?\d|1[0-2]):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i", '$start')) :
    $errors->add('submit_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The time is incorrect', 'appthemes'));
}
```

It will first look at the state of the field then move to the validation if required.

EDIT
Sorry, just realised there is an optimal way being:

```
if(!empty($start) && !preg_match("/(0?\d|1[0-2]):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i", '$start')) :
    $errors->add('submit_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The time is incorrect', 'appthemes'));
endif;
```

Why the `!empty($start)`? Because it is using the standard PHP function that defines if the value is present or not. Not 100% required but is best practice to use the empty() function when determining if a value exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form data stored in `$start` :

```
if ($start && !preg_match("/(0?\d|1[0-2]):(0\d|[0-5]\d) (AM|PM)/i", '$start')) :
        $errors->add('submit_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: The time is incorrect', 'appthemes'));
        endif;
```